# PHP Frameworks and Project Repositories

Tags: php, git, github, zend-framework2, repository

I'm starting a new in PHP and for the first time I'm going to use a framework as the basis of the project. I've decided to use Zend Framework 2 for it.

I'm going to be version controlling the project via Github.

Is it normal to include all the framework files in the project repository, updating and committing updates of the framework as part of my repository? Or would it normally be kept separate so you can download and use the current repository version whenever you install from the repository version of my project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md):

> Composer is a tool for dependency management in PHP. It allows you to declare the dependent libraries your project needs and it will install them in your project for you.

1. [Install Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx)
2. Run `composer require 'zendframework/zendframework:2.5.1'`

   - This will create or update your `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files
   - These files [should be committed to version control](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file)
   - It will also create or update your `vendor/` directory, where libraries will be stored
   - The `vendor/` directory [should *not* be committed](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md)
3. Use the [generated autoloader](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading)

Other developers should run the `composer install` command on their machines. This will install all of the project dependencies defined in `composer.json` and `composer.lock`.

If you update your dependencies, run `composer update` and commit the changed `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files.

For more details, [check out the Zend](http://framework.zend.com/downloads/composer) and Composer websites.